# Why are my onclick methods returning Slider not defined?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a fairly simple javascript creating a slider, but the onclick function is returning an error, and I can't figure out why.

http://jsfiddle.net/wxPWk/

```
var Slider = {
    content: ["text", "img"],
    current: 0,
    render: function(){
        view.innerHTML = this.content[this.current];
    },
    changeSlide: function(dir){
        if(dir) {
             this.current=0;

            return
        } else {
        this.current=1;
        }
        this.render();
    }
}
```

and in HTML I've got

```
<a onclick="Slider.changeSlide('back')"><</a> <a onclick="Slider.changeSlide()">></a>
```

but clicking the link I get a `Slider is undefined` error.

Comment: Off topic: Anchors require non-empty `href` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix is to declare `Slider` outside `window.onload` and assign it in `window.onload`:

```
var Slider = {};

window.onload = function() {
    Slider = {
        changeSlide: ...
    }
}
```

A better solution is to define `Slider` outside `window.onload` as Isherwood proposed. Then you have to put the stand-alone `Slider.render()` inside `window.onload`.

```
var Slider = {
    ...
    changeSlide: function(dir) {
        if (dir) {
            this.current = 0;
        } else {
            this.current = 1;
        }
        this.render();
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    Slider.render();
}
```

Note that `document.getElementById('slide')` will only yield the correct `div` after the HTML has been rendered, so you should make the `view` variable part of the `render` function:

```
var Slider = {
    content: ["text", "img"],
    current: 0,
    render: function() {
        var view = document.getElementById('slide');        
        view.innerHTML = this.content[this.current];
    }, ...
 }
```

or assign a value to `view` in `window.onload`.

Comment: In the end I used jsfiddles no-wrap in body. I had no idea what that did before.  http://jsfiddle.net/3Raf8/

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the JavaScript load parameter to 'No wrap - in ' so it's available:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wxPWk/2/

```
That raises other errors, unfortunately.
```